# Hibernate JPA Error

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have been trying to get data from database using Hibernate+JPA in Spring 3.0 project. It is giving me exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE. Here I am giving complete stack trace.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)
at org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.<init>(TypeResolver.java:59)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:250)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:302)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:98)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:133)
at   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
at com.mpm.login.service.UserAuthentication.authenticateUser(UserAuthentication.java:30)
at com.mpm.login.controller.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

### My Dependency Tree looks like as per below:

```
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ Login ---
[INFO] Login:Login:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compil
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:co
ile 
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Fina
compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0-rev-1:compile
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### LoginConroller.java

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value = "login.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody HashMap authenticate(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                      @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
       HashMap loginMap = new HashMap();

```
   System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
   System.out.println("uname "+ username + "pass "+password);

   Login userLogin = new Login();
   userLogin.setUsername(username);
   userLogin.setPassword(password);

   //Conectivity to JPA 
   System.out.println("IP Address:"+request.getRemoteAddr());
   System.out.println("HOST:"+request.getRemoteHost());
   System.out.println("Port:"+request.getRemotePort());
   System.out.println("User:"+request.getRemoteUser());
   System.out.println("Browser:"+request.getHeader("User-Agent"));

   /*
    * Write the code to audit the login detail in login audit table 
   */

   UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication();
   boolean isUserAuthenticated=userAuthentication.authenticateUser(username, password);
   System.out.println("auth is "+isUserAuthenticated);
   userLogin.setIsUserAuthenticated(isUserAuthenticated?"true":"false");
  // req.setAttribute("status", isUserAuthenticated);
 //  loginMap.put("data", userLogin);
   loginMap.put("success", isUserAuthenticated);
   //request.setAttribute
   //System.out.println("----"+ login.u);
   System.out.println("----");
  // System.out.println("final result is... " + userAuthenticate);
   return loginMap;
   //return "redirect:success.jsp";
  // return "{success:true}";
```

}

}

### UserAuthentication.java

public class UserAuthentication {

```
/**
 * @param args
 * Authenticates User from database and returns true  
 * if user is authenticated
 */
public boolean authenticateUser(String uname, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(" Inside authenticateUser");
    boolean userAuthenticate=false;
    List lst=null;
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DBConnection");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    System.out.println(" Before Try block");
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        //Select all the record from Login table
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT l FROM Login l where l.username = '"+uname+"' and l.password='"+password+"'");
        System.out.println("query = " + query);
        lst = query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("lst = "+lst.size());
        if(lst.size()>0)

            userAuthenticate=true;
            /*Login login = (Login) it.next();
            System.out.print("Id:"+login.getId());
            System.out.print(" Name:"+login.getUname());
            System.out.println(" Password:"+login.getPassword());*/

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("in catch");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }
     return userAuthenticate;
}
```

}

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
<persistence-unit name="DBConnection">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<class>com.mpm.login.model.Login</class>
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <!--
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    -->
</properties>
```

### pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Login</groupId>
    <artifactId>Login</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Login</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
    <finalName>Login</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.hibernate.version>3.3.1.GA</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.springframework.test.version>2.5</org.springframework.test.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Adding the Servlet 2.4 Specification as a Dependency -->

         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Adding the JSP 2.0 Specification as a Dependency --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Adding the logging Dependency --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rev-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>JBoss</id>
    <name>JBoss repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
    </repository>  
    </repositories>
    </project>
```

Can anyone help to resolve this issue? What could be cause of this error and how it can be resolved?

Thanks
Kapil

### Exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.mpm.login.service.UserAuthentication.authenticateUser(UserAuthentication.java:30)
    at com.mpm.login.controller.LoginController.authenticate(LoginController.java:50)
```

Comment: Not enough information , at least you should provide the codes of `com.mpm.login.service.UserAuthentication.authenticateUser()` and `com.mpm.login.controller.LoginController.authenticate()` .

Comment: hi Ken, please see the code below.                                                                public boolean authenticateUser(String uname, String password) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println(" Inside authenticateUser");
  boolean userAuthenticate=false;
  List lst=null;
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DBConnection");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  System.out.println(" Before Try block");

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "login.action", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody HashMap authenticate(@RequestParam("username") String username,
          @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HashMap loginMap = new HashMap();
       
       UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication();
       boolean isUserAuthenticated=userAuthentication.authenticateUser(username, password);
       System.out.println("auth is "+isUserAuthenticated);

Comment: Don't put the code in the comment , posting them by editing your post please

Comment: I have added code in post. Please have a look and let me know.

Comment: `at org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.<init>(BasicTypeRegistry.java:94)` . Searching from Google seems that this problem is because of several different versions of Hibernate related Jars in the class-path . What is your pom.xml?

Comment: Ken, I have posted my pom.xml above. I have been searching for the other version hibernate jar file but couldn't get it.

Comment: You can try to remove `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` from the pom.xml as it is included in the `hibernate-entitymanager` .Also remove `persistence-api 1.0-rev-1` because it is the old version of `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api`. I hope this will work

Comment: Ken, I have done changes. Now I am getting other exception which I put above. What could be cause of that?

Comment: It is strange , that class should be included in the `hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.9.Final.jar`

Comment: what could be other issue that you think?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your "com.mpm.login.model.Login" file has any variable declared as `INSTANCE` If it is there then it is not able to map that variable with the database column.

Comment: there is not any variable declared as INSTANCE in mentioned class. The INSTANCE variable is there BasicTypeRegistry.java which is a hibernate library file. So any other clue?

Comment: I am using following library files for my Hibernate and OpenJPA Project

Comment: But I am not using EJB.

dom4j-1.6.1.jar,  
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar,  
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar,  
hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar,  
hibernate3-3.3.2.GA.jar,  
javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar,  
log4j-1.2.16.jar,  
mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar,  
openjpa-all-2.0.0-M3.jar,  
oscache-2.4.1.jar,  
slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar,  
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar  

As you are using EJB3 do you have `ejb3-persistence.jar` file?

Comment: I also not using EJB here. I don't have ejb3-persistence.jar file. I think we don;t require this file as entitymanager.jar would handle this. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899057/hibernate-in-glassfish-ejb3configuration-noclassdeffounderror) and [this](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/NoMoreHibernateannotationsModule)

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750141/problems-initilicing-ejb3configuration-maven-hibernate-jpa-spring)